# Session data doesn't persist using Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, vite, express-session

Im building a simple Sign In / Log In client and I want to store a "client ID" in a session when they do either Sign In or Log In, then the client will access the session info to retrieve the clientID and use that to render a UserDetails page.
The problem is that when I save the userID on the session, I try to access it on another request and there is no data stored.

Im building a simple Sign In / Log In client and I want to store a "client ID" in a session when they do either Sign In or Log In.

Here is my express session configuration:

```
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

const app = express();
app.use(sessions({
    secret: `${process.env.SESSION_SECRET}`,
    saveUninitialized:false,
    cookie: { maxAge: oneDay },
    resave: false,
}));
```

Because my server and client are working on different ports I'm also using CORS as follows:

```
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
        methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE',
        credentials: true,
    })
);
```

The userId's are stored in a Postgres DB and I access them by providing an email and password, here is my function to logIn

```
const logIn = (req, res) =>{
    const email = req.body.body.email
    const password = sign(req.body.body.password,process.env.ENCODE_SECRET)
    pool.query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = $1 AND password = $2', [email, password], (error, results) =>{
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        req.session.user = results.rows[0];
        console.log(req.session);
        res.status(200).json({
            error: false, 
            message: 'Log in success',
            user: results.rows[0],
        }); 
        }
    });
}
```

The session looks like this on the console.log()

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-08-04T18:32:12.698Z,
    originalMaxAge: 86400000,
    httpOnly: true
  },
  user: { id: 21 }
}
```

Then I have a function to check if there is an active session on the client's root directrory to then store the userId and then redirect to the UserInformation page

```
const logInSuccess = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session)
    if (req.session.user) {
        console.log('usuario en sesion')
        res.status(200).json({
            error: false, 
            message: 'Log In Success',
            user: req.session.user,
        });
    } else {
        res.status(403).json({error: true, message: 'Not Authorized'});
    }
}
```

The console.log() shows a new cookie with no user data

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-08-04T18:32:13.026Z,
    originalMaxAge: 86400000,
    httpOnly: true
  }
}
```

The logInSuccess function returns the 403 status because there is no user data on the session.

On my client I'm using a Vite + React app with Axios for my requests, and all of my requests have the "withCredentials: true" configuration as shown in this example

```
const result = await axios.post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_API_URL}/login`,{
   withCredentials: true,
   headers: {Accept: 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
   body: userDetails,
})
```

I've seen many StackOverflow posts on this issue and tried the solutions provided but the problem still persists.

If someone could help me figure out what can be done to solve this it would be greatly appreciated.

If additional info is required please let me know.

Comment: Have you already solved the problem or not? Please tag me @RokBenko so that I'll see when you reply.

Comment: @RokBenko I haven't solved this issue yet, right now I am trying to create a server using Ruby on Rails but if there is a way to solve the server I would greatly appreciate the help